# JIRA group statuses (steps) under a common name

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We prepare to use JIRA to customise a project.

The situation is that we have so many statuses(steps) in the project, like a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h..., we want to group some of the statuses together under a common name, for example, name A includes a,b,c and name B includes d,e,f....something like that.

Anyone knows whether there is such existing function in JIRA or plugins which can satisfy the requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA doesn't do hierarchical workflows. The simplest way is to give all your status names prefixes, e.g. A:a, A:b, A:c, B:d etc